# Let V be a finite dimensional vector space over a field F. A linear transformation P : V→V is called a projection if P^2=P.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if P is a projection, then V=N(P)(+)R(P).

Is my problem and if someone could help me start the problem + also improve how I typed in my question it would be greatly appreciated.

N(P) -: Nullity of P,
R(P) -: Rank of P,
(+) -: direct sum (I tried entering it correctly but to no avail.)

Many thanks for any answers.

Comment: Usual notation: $N(P)={\rm Ker}\,P$, $R(P)={\rm Im}\,P$. Direct sum $\oplus$ is \oplus.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\;\;\forall\,x\in V\,,\,\,\text{write}\;\;x= Px+(x-Px). \;\text{Now prove 
that}\;\;V=\ker P+\text{Im}\,P\\
(2)&\;\;x\in\ker P\cap \text{Im}\,P\implies Px=0\;\;and\;\;x=Py\;,\;\;y\in V\implies 0=Px=P^2y=Py\ldots\end{align*}$$